# How to verify the solution to n queens problem

Tags: time-complexity

I have made an algorithm by which I recently finished counting solutions to 28 queens problem and I have the number. How do I verify that it is correct?

I have heard that it can be done in quadratic time. That is, given a solution to an nqueen problem it can be verified in polynomial time. I would like to know the algorithm too.

Thanks

Comment: Compare to the 28th value in https://oeis.org/A000170 if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what they meant was that if you are given a placement of $n$ queens, you can verify in quadratic time whether that is a valid solution (i.e., none of the queens attack any of the others).

I don't know of any way to verify the count of the number of solutions in quadratic time, and I doubt that such a thing is possible in quadratic time.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of any way to determine the count that is faster than finding all the solutions. There are quite a few problems like that, which may be quite unsatisfactory. In this case, even if I gave a list of all solutions, proving that there are no others would be hard.

So there is likely no *fast* way to check that your solution is correct. Actually, even checking it in a slow way is hard. You might run your software translated to a different programming language, using a different compiler, using a different computer, to check that your solution is not incorrect due to unexpected behaviour of the programming language, bugs in the compiler, or hardware bugs.

That doesn't rule out errors in your algorithm or in your implementation, so you could get a bit more confident if someone else solved the same problem independently from you and came up with the same answer. On the other hand, there may be some subtlety in the problem that both you and the other implementor missed and that means you have identical but wrong answers.